# C++ regex pattern to match datetime for both Windows and Posix systems

Tags: c++, regex

I would like to match datetime in a string like this:

`Blah blah blah 2015/11/03 20:25:50 blah blah blah`

My application must work well on both Windows and Linux. I am going to use std::tr1 for Windows version and regex (regex.h) for Linux version. Now I need to write a regex pattern that can work with both std::tr1 on Windows and regex on Linux. Please help!

Update:

This works for me on Windows, but it doesn't work on Linux

```
"(\\d{4})\\/(\\d{2})\\/(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})"
```

Comment: You should really try writing it yourself first, and then describing to us what isn't working. A good tool to help you would be http://regexr.com/

Comment: Don't use `std::tr1`, it's obsolete. Unless you have a *very* old compiler (in which case it's not certain that regular expressions will be fully implemented, if at all).

Comment: Escape braces or use \\d several times Iinstead. regex.h supports limiting quantifiers but they need to be escaped or use a REG_EXTENDED flag - then you won't have to escape braces.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `tryParse()` [(see here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) instead of trying to do this with RegEx?

Comment: "doesn't work" ... ? Why not try breaking it down to discover the specific regex feature not supported by your library? Then you can simply look it up and discover how to fix it. This is called _research_ and we are not here to do that for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex in both Windows ([C++ regex module](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)) and Linux ([regex.h module](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/regex.h.html)):

```
([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})
```

Remove the groups if you are not interested in the captured texts.

Here is a [regex.h Linux demo](https://ideone.com/PzX0fb) showing that the match is found. And here is the same regex in [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/HZVIWn).

The thing is that in regex.h, POSIX BRE regex is used by default, and you need to use `REG_EXTENDED` flag to use POSIX ERE standard (where you do not need to eascape braces and brackets.)

See this [POSIX reference](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions):

> **`BRE: \{m,n\}`**
>   **`ERE: {m,n}`**
>   Matches the preceding element at least m and not more than n times. For example, `a\{3,5\}` matches only "aaa", "aaaa", and "aaaaa". This is not found in a few older instances of regular expressions.

Note that you can use `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[0-9]` in POSIX.